# Drawing div borders with CSS or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-experience

My goal to add some animation to the borders of my div elements on one of my web pages.

I'm wondering how I would go about drawing/animating borders for my list of div's on a `onHover` event.

Is this possible with JQuery or CSS3?

Comment: What sort of animation are you thinking of? I'm sure you can do some basic things with either JS or CSS, but it depends what you want :)

Comment: I'm sure there are many resources you can find for animating on the `onHover` event. This QA forum is for specific questions. What have you tried? What is giving you a problem?

Comment: please show some work that you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I would recommend you use CSS for animation unless you're working with (very) old browser, and even then generally I would only fall back to JS if the animation is essential to the page.

You can do basic animation with a simple CSS transition:

```css
.example{
  border: 2px solid #dd0;
  
  -moz-transition: border linear 1s;
  -o-transition: border linear 1s;
  -webkit-transition: border linear 1s;
  transition: border linear 1s;
}
.example:hover{
  border: 2px solid #000
}
```

```html
<div class="example">This is some text</div>
```

There are also more complex methods you could try, [such as this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-animated-dashed-border/) which uses keyframes to animate a dashed border. Example below (Taken and modified from that tutorial):

```css
.animation-examples {
  width: 600px;
  height: 120px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: cambria;
  color: #69D2E7;
  outline: 10px dashed #E0E4CC;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #69D2E7;
}

.animation-examples.one:hover {
  animation: 1s animateBorderOne ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateBorderOne {
  0% {
    outline-color: #E0E4CC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #69D2E7;
  }
  50% {
    outline-color: #69D2E7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #E0E4CC;
  }
  100% {
    outline-color: #E0E4CC;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px #69D2E7;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="animation-examples">
  <div class="animation-examples one">
    Sample Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use **css animation**. It works essentially on keyframes.

Here's your div :

```
<div>
What a test.
</div>
```

Now your css :

```
div {
  border: 3px solid black;
}

div:hover {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: color;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    border-color: darkred;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: orange;
  }

}
```

This example is widely inspired from one i found (maybe in SO). Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pLgwgs74/). More examples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).